# MinGW crash if not compiled with -static-libstdc++

Tags: c++, windows, g++, mingw, libstdc++

I'm using MinGW with g++ (5.3.0) to compile C and C++ for a while now.

I'm pretty sure I changed nothing but apparently I did because when I compiled my DLLs I noticed I couldn't load them when I used std::string or std::unique_ptr.
Later on I noticed that every single programm I compiled just crashed on startup.

Kinda got around that using -static-libstdc++ as a linker flag, which blew up my file sizes.

Today I fired up my computer and everything went nuts.

[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
int main() {}
```

When compiling with `g++ sscce.cpp -o sscce.exe` it works, but when I do

```
g++ -c sscce.cpp -o sscce.o
g++ sscce.o -o sscce.exe
```

I get this:

```
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x280): multiple definition of `_mingw32_init_mainargs'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x280): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2c0): multiple definition of `mainCRTStartup'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2c0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2e0): multiple definition of `WinMainCRTStartup'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x2e0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x300): multiple definition of `atexit'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x300): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x310): multiple definition of `_onexit'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.text+0x310): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x320): multiple definition of `__gcc_register_frame'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtbegin.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x410): multiple definition of `__gcc_deregister_frame'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtbegin.o:(.text+0xf0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x4): multiple definition of `_argc'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x4): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `_argv'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/../../../crt2.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
main.o:main.cpp:(.eh_fram+0xc8): multiple definition of `__EH_FRAME_BEGIN__'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtbegin.o:(.eh_frame+0x0): first defined here
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/5.3.0/crtbegin.o:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `_Jv_RegisterClasses'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why does this happen and what can I do to make it stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literally didn't touch anything, not even my PC, and now it works again.